Rails Join and Includes Not Returning Extra Data
I have two models, Appointment and Teacher. Teacher is a sub-class of User. I want to have a controller return a scope for Appointment but join and includes with Teacher so that I can return all of the data from that table. However, either the data will only be from the Appointment scope or will give me the error Object doesn't support #inspect, primarily when I use the includes or select methods after joins. Did I make a mistake somewhere or is this just not possible?
class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :teacher, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :student, class_name: "User", optional: true

  validates :start_datetime, uniqueness: true

  scope :all_available_appts, -> { where(status: "Available") }

  scope :all_available_appts_for_date, ->(date) { all_available_appts.where(start_datetime: date.to_date.beginning_of_day..date.to_date.end_of_day) }
end

class Teacher < User
    has_many :appointments
end

class Student < User
    has_many :appointments
end

 def available_appointments_for_date
        student = Student.find_by(id: params[:student_id])
        if student
            render json: {
                appointments: Appointment.all_available_appts_for_date(params[:date]).joins(:teacher).includes(:first_name, :last_name)
                 # appointments: Appointment.eager_load(:users).all_available_appts_for_date(params[:date]).select('users.*, appointments.*')
            }
        else
            render json: {
                status: 500,
                error: "Student or appointments not found"
            }
        end
    end


I think you are confusing ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#includes with the include option supported by ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON#as_json

@engineersmnky your suggestion worked, but why isn't includes(:first_name).select('users.*') working?

Because ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#includes takes a list of associations which are eager loaded - not attributes. Do  yourself a favor and move the query up a row (assign it to a local var) and use a sensible line length and it will be easier to follow th code.
